# Mef and Configuration File Settings

Tags: mef

New to Mef so I m on a discovery tour.
I was wondering whether you could read from Configuration file like Unity does.

I mean configure an Interface and mapto a class and sort of resolve it.

Lets take an example "Plugins"
I could take the approach of creating a folder "Plugins" and MEF would happily read all the plugins.
What about if I wanted to define the classes/interfaces I want to use in a config file like unity.
Can this be done or Am I missing the point with mef?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MEF doesn't support this by default.  I believe there is a configuration-based programming model on [MefContrib](http://github.com/mefcontrib) that does this.

Comment: Or simply use Unity, which is perfect for what you described.